# Преобразование QtGui.QImage в черно-белое изображение

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qimage

Как изображение `QtGui.QImage` преобразовать в черно-белое изображение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, все возможно, попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ImageConverter(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        openButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open...')
        layout.addWidget(openButton, 0, 0)
        openButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)

        # отображение меток и их функций
        conversions = [
            ('Original',        self.asOriginal), 
            ('Negative',        self.toNegative), 
            ('Gray scale',      self.toGray), 
            ('Monochrome',      self.toMono), 
            ('Horizontal Flip', self.hFlip), 
            ('Vertical Flip',   self.vFlip), 
            ('Brightness',      self.brightness)
        ]

        self.convertCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.convertCombo, 0, 1)
        for label, func in conversions:
            # установить данные каждого элемента в функцию, которая будет изменять 
            # изображение, тогда мы можем получить доступ к этой функции 
            # из выбранного в данный момент элемента
            self.convertCombo.addItem(label, func)
        self.convertCombo.setEnabled(False)        # закрыто, пока не выбрана картинка

        self.brightnessTimer = QtCore.QTimer(
            singleShot=True,                 
            interval=500, 
            timeout=self.brightness
        )

        self.brightnessSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        layout.addWidget(self.brightnessSlider, 0, 2)
        self.brightnessSlider.setEnabled(False)
        self.brightnessSlider.setValue(50)
        self.brightnessSlider.setRange(0, 100)

        # простая метка, показывающая значение яркости
        self.brightnessLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('50 %')
        layout.addWidget(self.brightnessLabel, 0, 3)

        self.original = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.original, 1, 0)

        self.transformed = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.transformed, 1, 1, 1, 3)

        # каждый раз, когда элемент выбран, 
        # вызывайте набор функций в качестве данных элемента, 
        # чтобы преобразование выполнялось автоматически;
        self.convertCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(
            lambda i: self.convertCombo.itemData(i)()  
        )
        # включить ползунок, только если выбран режим яркости
        self.convertCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(
            lambda i: self.brightnessSlider.setEnabled(
                i == len(conversions) - 1)
        )
        # не делайте вычисление яркости при каждом изменении значения, 
        # но только через некоторое время значение изменяется
        self.brightnessSlider.valueChanged.connect(
            self.brightnessTimer.start)
        self.brightnessSlider.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda v: self.brightnessLabel.setText('{} %'.format(v)))

    def openFile(self):
        path, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Select image', '')
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(path)
        if not pixmap.isNull(): 
            self.original.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.convertCombo.setEnabled(True)
            self.convertCombo.currentData()()  

    def asOriginal(self):
        self.transformed.setPixmap(self.original.pixmap())

    def toNegative(self):
        image = self.original.pixmap().toImage()
        image.invertPixels()
        self.transformed.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def toGray(self):
        image = self.original.pixmap().toImage()
        transformed = image.convertToFormat(QtGui.QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
        self.transformed.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(transformed))

    def toMono(self):
        image = self.original.pixmap().toImage()
        transformed = image.convertToFormat(QtGui.QImage.Format_Mono)
        self.transformed.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(transformed))

    def hFlip(self):
        image = self.original.pixmap().toImage()
        transformed = image.mirrored(horizontal=True, vertical=False)
        self.transformed.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(transformed))

    def vFlip(self):
        image = self.original.pixmap().toImage()
        transformed = image.mirrored(horizontal=False, vertical=True)
        self.transformed.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(transformed))
    
    def brightness(self):
        image = self.original.pixmap().toImage()
        brightness = self.brightnessSlider.value()
        if brightness == 50:
            # яркость по умолчанию, используйте оригинальное изображение
            self.asOriginal()
            return
        elif brightness < 50:
            ratio = brightness / 50
            convFunc = lambda l: l * ratio
        else:
            ratio = (brightness - 50) / 50
            convFunc = lambda l: l + (1 - l) * ratio
        for r in range(image.height()):
            for c in range(image.width()):
                h, s, l, a = QtGui.QColor(image.pixel(c, r)).getHslF()
                image.setPixel(c, r, QtGui.QColor.fromHslF(
                    h, s, convFunc(l), a).rgba())
        self.transformed.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ImageConverter()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
size = image.size()
for i in range(size.width()):
    for j in range(size.height()):
        gray = qGray(image.pixel(i, j))
        image.setPixel(i, j, qRgb(gray, gray, gray))
```